# Self guided backcountry Monument Valley tour in a car like Outback?

Tags: off-road, utah, arizona

I am planning to visit Monument Valley, Utah/Arizona. I am going to take a new Subaru Outback we bought. Is it possible to do self guided back-country tour there, if I have a car like Outback? Or do you need to take a tour with an official guide?

Comment: @Giorgio that's not a reason to vote to close. If the question is on-topic here, it stays here. The question seems pretty reasonable. An Outback is a pretty common and well-known AWD vehicle, so the question is essentially asking whether it is possible to do a self-tour of Monument Valley in a privately owned AWD vehicle. That's not too hard to answer.

Comment: The answer from several sites online appears to be that private vehicles are not allowed off of the loop road, but I'm having trouble finding a sufficiently definitive source.

Answer (score 2):

You can drive the loop in Monument Valley with that car with no problem. I saw also smaller and lower cars driving the loop with no issue. The initial part is quite bumpy but if you drive carefully everything should be fine.

It's not possible to go on your own off the main loop, there are only guided tours in that case.